# How to retrieve tweets from company profile using java or json?

Tags: java, json, twitter

In twitter there are many companys which has their own profile like (ex : https://twitter.com/starbucks or https://twitter.com/mcdonalds). i want to get latest tweets from the company profiles. i have the below code using JSON but it returns general search with keyword from latest tweets.

```
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(  
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));  
        String urlstr = "http://twitter.com/search.json?q=";  
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();  

        System.out.print("Search for : ");  
        urlstr += in.readLine();  

        URL url = new URL(urlstr);  
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(  
                                    new InputStreamReader(  
                                    url.openConnection().getInputStream()));  
        int c;  
        while((c=br.read())!=-1)  
        {  
            buff.append((char)c);  
        }  
        br.close();  

        JSONObject js = new JSONObject(buff.toString());  
        JSONArray tweets = js.getJSONArray("results");  
        JSONObject tweet;  
        for(int i=0;i<tweets.length();i++) {  
            tweet = tweets.getJSONObject(i);  
            System.out.println((i+1)+") "+tweet.getString("from_user")+" at   
                "+tweet.getString("created_at"));  
            System.out.println(tweets.getJSONObject(i).getString("text")+"\n");  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: There are Twitter APIs in Java.

Comment: The Correct Url is urlstr="http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from%3AMcDonalds";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Correct Url is 
 String urlstr="http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from%3AMcDonalds";